# how to redirect to other page by using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm inserting data by using json in this page `http://localhost:4858/dash/page/Insert.aspx` and its working fine, but after inserting record successfully i want to redirect to this page `http://localhost:4858/Record.aspx`. 
But its not redirectly to target page, getting error like this in url `http://localhost:4858/dash/page/Record.aspx` i don't understand how to remove this `/dash/page/` from url

this is my JSON Code i'm using in my page

```
$.ajax({   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           type: 'post',
           url: 'Insert.aspx/InsertRecord',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify({
                 FirstName: FirstName,
                 LastName:LastName,
                 Gender:Gender,
                 Phone:Phone,
                 Email:Email
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                       //window.location="Record.aspx";
                        window.location.replace('Record.aspx');

                    },
                    error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("status=" + textStatus + ", error=" + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `window.location.replace` use:

```
location.href = "/Record.aspx";
```

Mind the `/` as the first character, which takes you to the root. Also, note that it's `location.href` or `window.location.href` and not `window.location`.